# Parsing JSON with aeson for a compound data type

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have following data type:

```
data DocumentOrDirectory = Document DocumentName DocumentContent 
                         | Directory DirectoryName [DocumentOrDirectory]
```

I came with with following code for toJSON. It works, but needs improvement. It should convert Document and Directory separately, but I don't know how to do it.

```
instance JSON.ToJSON DocumentOrDirectory where
    toJSON (Document documentName documentContent) = JSON.object
        [ "document" JSON..= JSON.object 
            [ "name" JSON..= (T.pack $ id documentName)
            , "content" JSON..= (T.pack $ id documentContent)
            ]
        ]
    toJSON (Directory dirName dirContent) = JSON.object
        [ "directory" JSON..= JSON.object 
            [ "name" JSON..= (T.pack $ id dirName)
            , "content" JSON..= JSON.toJSON dirContent
            ]
        ]
```

I need to be able to parse DocumentOrDirectory object from JSON. This is what I came up with (doesn't work):

```
instance JSON.FromJSON DocumentOrDirectory where
    parseJSON (Object v@(Document documentName documentContent)) = 
        DocumentOrDirectory <$> documentName .: "name"
                            <*> documentContent .: "content"
    parseJSON (Object v@(Directory dirName dirContent) = 
        DocumentOrDirectory <$> dirName .: "name"
                            <*> dirContent .: "content"
    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

How should I modify existing code to be able to convert data from and to JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's approach this problem step-by-step.

First I assume for the sake of the example that names and content are just `String`:

```
type DirectoryName = String
type DocumentName = String
type DocumentContent = String
```

You mention that you want to serialise `Document` and `Directory` separately. Maybe you want to work with them separately otherwise too. Let's make them separate types:

```
data Document = Document DocumentName DocumentContent deriving Show
data Directory = Directory DirectoryName [DocumentOrDirectory] deriving Show
newtype DocumentOrDirectory = DocumentOrDirectory (Either Document Directory) deriving Show
```

Now the `DocumentOrDirectory` is a type alias or `Either Document Directory`. We used `newtype`, because we want to write own instance for it. Default `Either` instance won't work for us.

And let define few helper functions:

```
liftDocument :: Document -> DocumentOrDirectory
liftDocument = DocumentOrDirectory . Left

liftDirectory :: Directory -> DocumentOrDirectory
liftDirectory = DocumentOrDirectory . Right
```

With this definitions we can write separate `ToJSON` instances:

```
instance ToJSON Document where
  toJSON (Document name content) = object [ "document" .= object [
    "name"    .= name,
    "content" .= content ]]

instance ToJSON Directory where
  toJSON (Directory name content) = object [ "directory" .= object [
    "name"    .= name,
    "content" .= content ]]

instance ToJSON DocumentOrDirectory where
  toJSON (DocumentOrDirectory (Left d))  = toJSON d
  toJSON (DocumentOrDirectory (Right d)) = toJSON d
```

We should check how `Document` and `Directory` are serialised (I prettifyied the JSON output):

```
*Main> let document = Document "docname" "lorem"
*Main> B.putStr (encode document)

{
  "document": {
    "content": "lorem",
    "name": "docname"
  }
}

*Main> let directory = Directory "dirname" [Left document, Left document]
*Main> B.putStr (encode directory) >> putChar '\n'

{
  "directory": {
    "content": [
      {
        "document": {
          "content": "lorem",
          "name": "docname"
        }
      },
      {
        "document": {
          "content": "lorem",
          "name": "docname"
        }
      }
    ],
    "name": "directory"
  }
}
```

The `B.putStr (encode $ liftDirectory directory)` will result the same!

The next step is to write decoders, `FromJSON` instances. We see that the key (`directory` or `document`) shows whether the underlying data is `Directory` or `Document`. Thus the JSON format is non-overlapping (unambigious) so we can just try to parse `Document` and then `Directory`.

```
instance FromJSON Document where
  parseJSON (Object v) = maybe mzero parser $ HashMap.lookup "document" v
    where parser (Object v') = Document <$> v' .: "name"
                                        <*> v' .: "content"
          parser _           = mzero
  parseJSON _          = mzero

instance FromJSON Directory where
  parseJSON (Object v) = maybe mzero parser $ HashMap.lookup "directory" v
    where parser (Object v') = Directory <$> v' .: "name"
                                         <*> v' .: "content"
          parser _           = mzero
  parseJSON _          = mzero

instance FromJSON DocumentOrDirectory where
  parseJSON json = (liftDocument <$> parseJSON json) <|> (liftDirectory <$> parseJSON json)
```

And the check:

```
*Main> decode $ encode directory :: Maybe DocumentOrDirectory
Just (DocumentOrDirectory (Right (Directory "directory" [DocumentOrDirectory (Left (Document "docname" "lorem")),DocumentOrDirectory (Left (Document "docname" "lorem"))])))
```

---

We could serialise the data with *type tag* inside the object data, then serialisation and deserialisation would look a bit nicer:

```
instance ToJSON Document where
  toJSON (Document name content) = object [
    "type"    .= ("document" :: Text),
    "name"    .= name,
    "content" .= content ]
```

The generated document would be:

```
{
  "type": "document",
  "name": "docname",
  "content": "lorem"
}
```

And decoding:

```
instance FromJSON Document where
  -- We could have guard here
  parseJSON (Object v) = Document <$> v .: "name"
                                  <*> v .= "content" 

instance FromJSON DocumentOrDirectory where
  -- Here we check the type, and dynamically select appropriate subparser
  parseJSON (Object v) = do typ <- v .= "type"
                            case typ of
                              "document"  -> liftDocument $ parseJSON v
                              "directory" -> liftDirectory $ parseJSON v
                              _           -> mzero
```

---

In languages with subtyping, such scala you could have:

```
sealed trait DocumentOrDirectory
case class Document(name: String, content: String) extends DocumentOrDirectory
case class Directory(name: String, content: Seq[DocumentOrDirectory]) extends DocumentOrDirectory
```

one might argue that this approach (which relies on subtyping) is more convenient. In Haskell we are more explicit: `liftDocument` and `liftDirectory` can be thought as explicit type coercions / upcasts, if you like to think about *objects*.

---

*EDIT:* [the working code as gist](https://gist.github.com/phadej/c41e7363f2819681bbe3)

Comment: I am getting Not in scope: `HashMap.lookup'. How could I fix that?

Comment: You'll get it by `import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HashMap` (it's in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/phadej/c41e7363f2819681bbe3))

Comment: I am getting     Couldn't match type `unordered-containers-0.2.3.0:Data.HashMap.Base.HashMap
                           T.Text JSON.Value'
                  with `HashMap.HashMap k0 JSON.Value' 

after adding import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HashMap

Comment: You probably have different versions of `unordered-containers`:  the default one and another one used by `aeson`. What `cabal list unordered-containers` tells you? I'd use cabal (sandbox) for any Haskell project, to avoid *Cabal Hell*.

Comment: It says Default available version: 0.2.5.0
Installed versions: 0.2.3.0, 0.2.5.0

Comment: what would be the way to fix it?

Comment: Use cabal to make dependencies explicit: https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program

Comment: got it. added `unordered-containers=0.2.3.0` to the `build-depends` section of my cabal file

Comment: Could you please look at the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764668/recursive-json-parsing-in-haskell ? Thanks